# Can i download AWS Volume's Snapshot and mount in my local machine and boot from it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to get the EC2 Volume Snapshot / Image download in local machine and then mount it and boot from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import virtual machine images from your existing environment to `Amazon EC2 instances` and export them back to your `on-premises environment` using **VM Import/Export**.
See detail.
[VM Import/Export](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vm-import/)

You can see how to download and run Amazon Linux 2 as a Virtual Machine On-Premises. [Amazon Linux 2 as a Virtual Machine On-Premises](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-2-virtual-machine.html)